# Row Selection behaviour sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to let the User select multiple lines with only a mouseclick.
When I set

```
{selectionMode: "Multi", selectionBehavior: "Row"}
```

I only get this behaviour [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vizozutubi/edit?html,js,output).
Users can only select multiple Rows with CTRL + Mouseclick and also deselect Rows with CTRL + Mouseclick. If the User clicks on a Row to deselect it without pressing CTRL it deselects all other Rows.

Is there a chance to select and deselect rows with only a mouseclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have use the selectionMode as "MultiToggle".

http://jsbin.com/vizozutubi/edit?html,js,output